# accessing data from arabic access database

Tags: java, database, ms-access, unicode

I have an access database with English and Arabic letters and a java program.  When i select or insert data to that database from my Java program, it works with English words, but Arabic words are changed to question mark like: `????????`.

who can help me to solve it...

This is the code of the connection:

```
try {
    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\hamreen\\workspace\\advanced kurdish dictionary\\words.mdb;";
    //?useUnicode=true&charachterEncoding=utf-8
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(database+"?useUnicode=true&charachterEncoding=utf-8","","");
} catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e1);
}
```

The select code:

```
try {
    Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();
    stmt1.executeQuery("select * from AA where en like '"+text+"%' order by en asc");
    //   stmt1.executeQuery("select * from test where en='"+temp+"'");///  bo kurdi
    ResultSet rs1=stmt1.getResultSet();
    int count=1;
    while(rs1.next()&&count!=5){
        englishMeanTextArea.append(rs1.getString(1)+"\n\n");
        kurdishMeanTextArea.append(rs1.getString(2)+"\n\n");
        count++;
    }
}catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e1);
}
```

Comment: where are you accessing it?

Comment: i access it from the java program

Comment: there also you need to check how are you accessing it, can you paste a snippet?

Comment: that is it
   try {
    Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();
             stmt1.executeQuery("select * from AA where en like '"+text+"%' order by en asc");
             ResultSet rs1=stmt1.getResultSet();
             int count=1;
             while(rs1.next()&&count!=5){              englishMeanTextArea.append(rs1.getString(1)+"\n\n");
kurdishMeanTextArea.append(rs1.getString(2)+"\n\n");
              count++;
             }
         }catch (Exception e1) {
             System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e1);
         }